# How to constraint the width of a GridView widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, gridview, constraints, width, fixed

I've been trying for two days to add a fixed width to a Grid View in flutter but I couldn't.

I tried adding width or Box Constraint to a parent container but it didn't work.

I am building a web app so the screen width is often wider than a smartphone's.
this is how I want it to look like:

[fixed width for GridView in flutter example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GMk9.png)

### Objective:

constraint the width of the GridView Widget to have a max width of 1000 as an example.

### Edit:

if you face any issue with centering the parent container just rap it with a Center widget and that should work

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ResponsiveBuilder(), I want my Cards to have a max 350 width so I divide the screen width to 350, and round it up, then I get my nice "Wrap" effect.

Or you can use Wrap() and have a custom layout in it, I use Wrap to show small screen items, like tags.

```
ResponsiveBuilder(
        builder: (context, sizingInformation) {
          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
            child: GridView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: items.length,
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                mainAxisExtent: 150,
                crossAxisCount: (sizingInformation.localWidgetSize.width
                    / 350 ).round()
              ),
...
```

Answer (score -2):

Here you can use `crossAxisCount` property to add no of items in row. Then give the fixed to its child by wrapping it in a container.

```
  Container(
        width: 100, // HERE YOU CAN ADD THE WIDTH
        child: GridView.builder(
            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: list.length,
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
              childAspectRatio: 1,
              crossAxisCount: 4, // HERE YOU CAN ADD THE NO OF ITEMS PER LINE
              mainAxisSpacing: 5,
              crossAxisSpacing: 5,
            ),
            itemBuilder: _getListItemTile))
```

Comment: Mr muhammad I know how to add no of children in a row .. that's not what I want  .. I need to constraint the width of the GridView Widget to have a max width of 1000 as an example. like the picture I posted

Comment: i edit the answer you can wrap you whole gridview in container and give the width and also you can wrap your individual widget of grid view in container and also give them the width

Comment: thank you so much Mr. muhammad tameem rafay